# Generically get used memory for a value?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is there a function that would get currently used up memory for a value, something like `getSize :: Memory a => a -> NumberOfBytes` or `getNfSize :: Memory a => a -> NumberOfBytes`, first getting the size of how much something takes at the moment, `getNfSize` would evaluate the structure to normal form and get the size then.

I guess whether there is sharing within the value would also play a role.

Comment: What is `Memory a`?

Comment: At least it would have to be `IO`, because it's not pure. Do you count only the thing that is directly passed, or also everything it refers to?

Comment: The [heapsize](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/heapsize) package provides the functions you're looking for.

Comment: Note that a function value like  `f :: Int -> Int` does not have an intrinsic fixed memory footprint. E.g. `f = let xs = [1,2,3] in \x -> sum (map (x^) xs)` needs to keep the list in memory somewhere, and the size of the list can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Sorry, fixed now. The typeclass would mean all types who's memory consumption is gettable.

Comment: @user253751Everything inside as well, i.e when passed a hashmap, then all its keys and values, and everything they link to.

Comment: “Everything they link to” is hardly a well-defined concept in Haskell. Only the runtime can determine this, and that seems to be what the `heapsize` package implements.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It is well defined, no? If a data constructor has a field value for some other type then it links to that.

Comment: @CigaretteSmokingMan but that's not all there is to consider. As chi mentioned, functions can have stuff in their closure that is referenced by not directly accessible. Similar for thunks, and that can change a lot during evaluation. Things may be shared between different bindings, how do you count that? If you define `a = someBigArray` and then `b = a`, does then `b` _use_ the memory? Etc. etc..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I determine size of a type in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492801/how-can-i-determine-size-of-a-type-in-haskell)