# Existential data types with a single strict field

Tags: haskell, existential-type, strictness

So I have an existential data type with a single strict field:

```
data Uncurry (a :: i -> j -> *) (z :: (i,j)) =
  forall x y. z ~ '(x,y) => Uncurry !(a x y)
```

Experimentation using `unsafeSizeof` (stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575209/9859)) leads me to believe that it can be zero memory-overhead:

```
λ p = (0, '\0') :: (Int, Char)
λ q = Uncurry p
λ unsafeSizeof p
10
λ unsafeSizeof q
10
```

So it seems like `Uncurry` is sort of acting like a `newtype`, being used only at compile time.

This makes sense to me, as the equality assertion doesn't require a dictionary to be carted about.

Is that a valid interpretation?  Do I have any guarantees of that from GHC (or the Haskell report), or did I just luck out?

Comment: It would be very nice to have this optimization. See https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/NewtypeOptimizationForGADTS. Unfortunately, the experts haven't figured out how to make everything work right yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`data` is never transformed to `newtype`. `Uncurry` does add a new closure, and a pointer for the `~` dictionary is actually also carted around, as of GHC 8.0.2. Hence, `Uncurry` has a closure with three words.

`unsafeSizeof` is incorrect, since `Array#` stores its size in words, while `ByteArray#` stores its size in bytes, so `sizeofByteArray# (unsafeCoerce# ptrs)` returns the number of words rather than the intended  number of bytes. A correct version would look like this on 64 bit systems:

```
unsafeSizeof :: a -> Int
unsafeSizeof !a =
  case unpackClosure# a of
    (# x, ptrs, nptrs #) ->
      I# (8# +# sizeofArray# nptrs *# 8# +# sizeofByteArray# ptrs)
```

But note that `unsafeSizeof` only gives us the size of the topmost closure. So, the closure size of any boxed tuple will be `24`, which coincides with the closure size of `Uncurry t`, since `Uncurry` has an info pointer, a useless pointer for `~`, and a pointer for the tuple field. This coincidence also holds with the previous buggy `unsafeSizeof` implementation. But the total size of `Uncurry t` is greater than that of `t`.

Answer (score 5):

*Edited* to fix some details re: quads being 8 bytes and explaining the static link field.

I think `unsafeSizeOf` is inaccurate *and* you're misinterpreting its output.  Note that it is intended to show the memory usage for the top-level closure only, not the total space usage of the object.  What you're seeing, I think, is that `q` requires 10 bytes in *addition* to the tuple `p` (while `p` requires 10 bytes in *addition* to the boxed `Char` and boxed `Int`).  Moreover, my tests indicate that the top-level constructors actually require 24 bytes each (on a 64-bit architecture), even though `unsafeSizeOf` reports 10 for me, too.

In particular, if I compile the following test program with `stack ghc -- -fforce-recomp -ddump-asm -dsuppress-all -O2 ZeroMemory.hs` using GHC 8.0.2:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module ZeroMemory where

data Uncurry (a :: i -> j -> *) (z :: (i, j)) =
  forall x y . z ~ '(x,y) => Uncurry !(a x y)

q :: Uncurry (,) '(Int, Char)
q = Uncurry (0, '\0')

r :: Uncurry (,) '(Int, Char)
r = Uncurry (1, '\1')
```

then the memory footprint for the top-level `q` closure looks like:

```
q_closure:
    .quad   Uncurry_static_info
    .quad   $s$WUncurry_$d~~_closure+1
    .quad   q1_closure+1
    .quad   3
```

Note that each `.quad` here is actually 8 bytes; it's a "quad" of old-style 16-bit "words".  I believe the final `quad` here, with value 3, is the "static link field" described in [the GHC implementation commentary](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects) and so doesn't apply to "typical" heap allocation objects.

So, ignoring this final field, the total size of the top-level `q` closure is 24 bytes, and it refers to the `q1_closure` which represents the contained tuple:

```
q1_closure:
    .quad   (,)_static_info
    .quad   q3_closure+1
    .quad   q2_closure+1
    .quad   3
```

for another 24 bytes.

The `q2` and `q3` closures are the boxed `Int` and `Char` and so take up two quads (16 bytes) each.  So, `q` takes up a total of 10 quads, or 80 bytes.  (I included `r` as a sanity check to make sure I wasn't misidentifying any shared info.)

A `p` tuple by itself would have a memory footprint equivalent to the `q1_closure`, so 7 quads or 56 bytes.