# Memory usage of constructors in haskell

Tags: memory, haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Memory footprint of Haskell data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254758/memory-footprint-of-haskell-data-types)

When solving combinatorial problems, I will often represent the solution as a bit string, eg. 1010100010110111000110... You get the picture.

I figured that when I use `[Int]` for the bit string, `Int` always spends the same amount of memory, no matter how big the number actually is (because `Int` it's bounded, in contrast to `Integer`), as the computer only remembers the bit representation, and `String`'s would take even more space as far as I know.

My idea was then to use the data type

```
data Bits = Empty | Zero Bits | One Bits deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
```

But how much memory do the constructors `Empty`, `Zero` and `One` use compared to `Int`'s?

Comment: An `Int` is always either 32 or 64 bits, so it can't store arbitrarily large numbers. `Integer`, on the otherhand, is unbounded.

Comment: Irrelevant to your question, but there is Data.Bits which has bitfield stuff

Comment: @dbaupp : I know that, that is why I wanted it compared to only `Int`'s

Comment: I once spent a long time carefully coding my information in binary and doing low-level bitmask operations on `Int`s because I felt I would have a big performance gain on using an abstract data type that represented my problem clearly. I was wrong. ghc compiled them both to be fast! Are you sure `0` and `1` are the clearest way for your problem? Can you reduce memory usage more effectively by carefully choosing strict and lazy? [However, this is an interesting question for general understanding.]

Comment: A representation of `[Bool]` is more space-efficient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Int` costs two words in memory (`#I` constructor and `#Int` field), your `Bits` data can use various cost, for example: `Zero (One (Zero Empty))` will cost:

1. One word for `Empty` constructor
2. Two words for `Zero` Constructor and field
3. Two words for `One` Constructor and field
4. Two words for `Zero` Constructor and field

and total cost — 7 words.
So memory amount for your data can be more than for `Int`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "words"? What is a "word" and how do I calculate it's memory usage?

Comment: It's a machine word, it's a 4 bytes in 32-bit machines and 8 bytes ins 64-bit.

Comment: I think I got my questioned answered here, since someone was kind enough to mark my question as a duplicate.