# Sizeof of algebraic data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Memory footprint of Haskell data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254758/memory-footprint-of-haskell-data-types)

Simple low-level newbie question, when I say something like

```
data SomeTree = Null | Red Int32 | Blue Int64 | Tree [SomeTree]
```

to construct trees, how **much bytes** does Haskell precisely use for each node, pointers etc. (64-bit machine code) when using GHC?

Comment: ...and also see [Memory usage of constructors in haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245410/memory-usage-of-constructors-in-haskell)

Comment: Thanks guys, good links.