# Memory footprint of existentially quantified types and related optimization techniques

Tags: haskell, memory, optimization

Consider the following data model utilizing an existential:

```
data Node a = Node a (Map TypeRep AnyNode)
data AnyNode = forall a. Show a => AnyNode a
```

The rules about memory footprint of standard types [have been explained previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256825/485115). Now, what are the rules for existential types, like `AnyNode`?

Are there any optimization techniques, e.g. some workarounds using `unsafeCoerce` making it possible to elude the existential declaration? I'm asking this because a type similar to `Node` is going to be placed in a cost centre of a highly memory-intensive lib, so memory footprint is all, that's why the most dirty hacks are welcome.

Comment: I reckon you've already considered the old "if you just require `Show`, then why not just store `show x` in the first place?"

Comment: @leftaroundabout The above is just an example. My actual case involves mutable data structures.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [ghc-datasize](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-datasize-0.1.1) package may be of help here:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, GADTs #-}

import GHC.DataSize

data Node = forall a. Show a => Node a 

main = do
    s <- closureSize $ Node 0 
    print s -- 24 bytes on my 64-bit system
```

So, it seems that `Node` takes one extra word compared to the plain unary data constructor, presumably because of the `Show` class dictionary pointer. Also, I tried adding more class constraints to `Node`, and each of them takes one extra word of space.

I don't know for sure whether it is possible to magic away the dictionary pointer in specific circumstances. I think it isn't possible if you'd like to keep the existential type.

Comment: That is one damn useful tool! Just playing with it in GHCi for a few minutes has opened my eyes on some aspects. E.g., a single `TypeRep` weighs 408 bytes - OMG, no thanks, I'll use a custom dictionary! However this doesn't completely answer my question, so I'll leave it open. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NikitaVolkov are you sure the `TypeRep`s are not shared (i.e. only one per program and type)?

Comment: @tibbe [According to docs on `recursiveSize`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-datasize-0.1.1/docs/GHC-DataSize.html), _the actual size in memory is calculated, so shared values are only counted once_. Calling `recursiveSize [typeOf 'a', typeOf 'b']` gives `520`, and `recursiveSize [typeOf 'a']` -
`272`. So it looks like no, they aren't shared, unfortunately.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: you may also want to muck around in compiled mode, possibly with optimizations, because the sizes sometimes change compared to GHCi.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov that sounds wrong. Can you file a bug against GHC?

Comment: @tibbe I've just retested this stuff in "-O2" mode and `TypeRep` of absolutely anything seems to be weighing just 16 bytes, i.e. 2 words on my 64-bit machine. Thanks for that bump!