# Optimizing a simple parser which is called many times

Tags: performance, haskell, attoparsec

I wrote a parser for a custom file using `attoparsec`. 
The profiling report indicated that around 67% of the memory allocation is done in a function named `tab`, which also consumes the most time. 
The `tab` function is pretty simple:

```
tab :: Parser Char
tab = char '\t'
```

The entire profiling report is as follows:

```
       ASnapshotParser +RTS -p -h -RTS

    total time  =       37.88 secs   (37882 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 54,255,105,384 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE    MODULE                %time %alloc

tab            Main                   83.1   67.7
main           Main                    6.4    4.2
readTextDevice Data.Text.IO.Internal   5.5   24.0
snapshotParser Main                    4.7    4.0


                                                             individual     inherited
COST CENTRE        MODULE                  no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN               MAIN                     75           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 CAF               Main                    149           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
  tab              Main                    156           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  snapshotParser   Main                    153           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main             Main                    150           1    6.4    4.2   100.0  100.0
   doStuff         Main                    152     1000398    0.3    0.0    88.1   71.8
    snapshotParser Main                    154           0    4.7    4.0    87.7   71.7
     tab           Main                    157           0   83.1   67.7    83.1   67.7
   readTextDevice  Data.Text.IO.Internal   151       40145    5.5   24.0     5.5   24.0
 CAF               Data.Text.Array         142           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF               Data.Text.Internal      140           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF               GHC.IO.Handle.FD        122           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF               GHC.Conc.Signal         103           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF               GHC.IO.Encoding         101           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF               GHC.IO.FD               100           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF               GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv    89           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main             Main                    155           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

How do I optimize this?

The entire code [for the parser is here.](https://gist.github.com/psibi/b218c4681989f6e3e705) The file which I'm parsing is around 77MB.

Comment: You do have a large number of calls to `tab` in the code.  Is it frequent that the parse fails to parse a record in your file?  It also seems like you might be better suited by splitting each line into a list of `String`s, then parsing each element to its corresponding field.  That way all the tabs are parsed up front.  You could also consider trying to find an existing CSV parser (there probably is one out there that support specifying a delimiter), which might be more optimized for a task like this.

Comment: @bheklilr To my knowledge, the parse doesn't fail for a single time even. The file is perfectly in that format as defined by the parser. I will use a CSV library and will update the results here. But still, I feel that the memory consumption and time taken is too high.

Comment: I've written lots of parsers, but not in Haskell. Are you using recursive-descent? In general, recursive-descent parsers should be IO-bound. To see if it's not, or why not, I use [*stackshots*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771), of which very few are needed.

Comment: I wonder how reliable profiling results are for `attoparsec` parsers.  Pretty much everything is INLINEd, and many optimizations don't take place when profiling is enabled.  Does the profiling run take significantly longer than execution without profiling?

Comment: @JohnL Yes you are correct. With the latest version it seems to matter a lot. But with the old version of attoparsec which I had been using initially, it didn't seem to affect much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tab` is a scapegoat. If you define `boo :: Parser (); boo = return ()` and insert a `boo` before every bind in the `snapshotParser` definition, the cost allocations will become something like:

```
 main             Main                    255           0   11.8   13.8   100.0  100.0
  doStuff         Main                    258     2097153    1.1    0.5    86.2   86.2
   snapshotParser Main                    260           0    0.4    0.1    85.1   85.7
    boo           Main                    262           0   71.0   73.2    84.8   85.5
     tab          Main                    265           0   13.8   12.3    13.8   12.3
```

So it seems the profiler is shifting the blame for the allocations of the parse results, likely due to extensive inlining of `attoparsec` code, as John L suggested in the comments.

As for the performance issues, the key point is that, as you are parsing a 77MB text file to build a list with a million elements, you want the file processing to be lazy, and not strict. Once that is sorted out, decoupling I/O and parsing in `doStuff` and building the list of snapshots without an accumulator are helpful as well. Here is a modified version of your program taking that into account.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where

import Data.Maybe
import Data.Attoparsec.Text.Lazy
import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as TL
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as TL

buildStuff :: TL.Text -> [Snapshot]
buildStuff text = case maybeResult (parse endOfInput text) of
  Just _ -> []
  Nothing -> case parse snapshotParser text of
      Done !i !r -> r : buildStuff i
      Fail _ _ _ -> []

main :: IO ()
main = do
  text <- TL.readFile "./snap.dat"
  let ss = buildStuff text
  print $ listToMaybe ss
    >> Just (fromIntegral (length $ show ss) / fromIntegral (length ss))

newtype VehicleId = VehicleId Int deriving Show
newtype Time = Time Int deriving Show
newtype LinkID = LinkID Int deriving Show
newtype NodeID = NodeID Int deriving Show
newtype LaneID = LaneID Int deriving Show

tab :: Parser Char
tab = char '\t'

-- UNPACK pragmas. GHC 7.8 unboxes small strict fields automatically;
-- however, it seems we still need the pragmas while profiling. 
data Snapshot = Snapshot {
  vehicle :: {-# UNPACK #-} !VehicleId,
  time :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Time,
  link :: {-# UNPACK #-} !LinkID,
  node :: {-# UNPACK #-} !NodeID,
  lane :: {-# UNPACK #-} !LaneID,
  distance :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Double,
  velocity :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Double,
  vehtype :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Int,
  acceler :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Double,
  driver :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Int,
  passengers :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Int,
  easting :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Double,
  northing :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Double,
  elevation :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Double,
  azimuth :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Double,
  user :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Int
  } deriving (Show)

-- No need for bang patterns here.
snapshotParser :: Parser Snapshot
snapshotParser = do
  sveh <- decimal
  tab
  stime <- decimal
  tab
  slink <- decimal
  tab
  snode <- decimal
  tab
  slane <- decimal
  tab
  sdistance <- double
  tab
  svelocity <- double
  tab
  svehtype <- decimal
  tab
  sacceler <- double
  tab
  sdriver <- decimal
  tab
  spassengers <- decimal
  tab
  seasting <- double
  tab
  snorthing <- double
  tab
  selevation <- double
  tab
  sazimuth <- double
  tab
  suser <- decimal
  endOfLine <|> endOfInput
  return $ Snapshot
    (VehicleId sveh) (Time stime) (LinkID slink) (NodeID snode)
    (LaneID slane) sdistance svelocity svehtype sacceler sdriver
    spassengers seasting snorthing selevation sazimuth suser
```

This version should have acceptable performance even if you force the whole list of snapshots into memory, as I did in `main` here. To gauge what is "acceptable", keep in mind that, given the sixteen (small, unboxed) fields in each `Snapshot` plus the [overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3254758/2751851) of the `Snapshot` and list constructors, we are talking about 152 bytes per list cell, which boils down to ~152MB for your test data. In any case, this version is about as lazy as possible, as you can see by removing the division in `main`, or replacing it by `last ss`.

N.B.: My tests were done with attoparsec-0.12.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "this version is about as lazy as possible, as you can see by removing the division in main, or replacing it by last ss." ? Did you remove the bang patterns in the parser because the Record data declaration is unboxed and strict or because of any other reason ?

Comment: By "as lazy as possible", I mean that if you, for instance, only ask for the last element it will spend a constant and tiny amount of memory. As for the bang patterns in the parser, I removed them because they made the performance worse. The strictness of the fields does make them redundant.

Answer (score 1):

After updating the attoparsec to the latest version ([0.12.0.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.12.0.0/docs/Data-Attoparsec.html)), the time taken to execute reduce from 38 seconds to 16 seconds. That's more than 50% speedup. Also the memory consumed by it reduced drastically. As @JohnL noted, with profiling enabled, the results are varying wildly. When I tried to profile it with the latest version of the attoparsec library, it took around 64 seconds to execute the whole program.