# reallyUnsafePtrEquality# on constructors with no fields

Tags: haskell, ghc

It's my understanding that the constructors of a type which have no fields are "statically allocated" and GHC [shares these between all uses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256825/176841), and that the [GC will not move these](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/DataTypes#Labelsandinfotables).

If that's correct then I would expect uses of [`reallyUnsafePtrEquality#`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.1-rc2/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.3.1.0/GHC-Prim.html#g:20) on values like `False` and `Nothing` to be very safe (no false negatives or positives), because they can only be represented as identical pointers to the single instance of that constructor.

Is my reasoning correct? Are there any potential gotchas, or reasons to suspect that this could become unsafe in near future versions of GHC?

Comment: Might be true. On the other hand, seems like for constructors with no fields the performance win over boring old `(==)` is going to be pretty minimal...

Comment: @DanielWagner My actual use case is working with the new CAS primops on boxed references. When using the `atomic-primops` library I'd like to be able to cache a `Ticket Nothing` (for instance) and be sure it never goes stale.

Comment: You might also need to be careful about plugins and the like.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Can you elaborate on that? You mean GHC plugins that could change those kind of low-level details and make my assumptions incorrect?

Comment: No, I meant that plugins that load code into a running Haskell program might wind up with their own copies of those nullary constructors. I don't know either way, but it's something I'd be worried about.

Comment: I think the only times that will happen are times when GHC won't consider them to be the same type anyway. It might still be a safe assumption.

Comment: I'm pretty sure nullary constructor pointers are re-written to point at the .TEXT only after they survive a GC.  Their initial allocation and pointer is still to dynamically allocated space which makes the technique proposed here unsafe.

Comment: I'm with Ganesh. I'd worry about plugins, and shared libs.

Answer (score 13):

I actually managed to get `reallyUnsafePtrEquality` to do the wrong thing.

Here's my minimal code example

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}
import GHC.Prim

-- Package it up nicely
ptrCmp :: a -> a -> Bool
ptrCmp a b = case (reallyUnsafePtrEquality# a b) of
  0# -> False
  1# -> True

main = do
  b <- readLn
  let a  = if b then Nothing else Just ()
      a' = Nothing
  print $ a == a'     -- Normal
  print $ ptrCmp a a' -- Evil
```

And doing something like

```
 $ ghc --version
   The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.2
 $ ghc unsafe.hs
 $ ./unsafe
   True
   True
   False
```

So... yes, `reallyUnsafePtrEquality` is still evil.

Comment: Worth noting that I have absolutely no clue **why** this happens. Just disproved this conjecture through a combination of dumb luck and trying pathological cases. If anyone could shed some light..

Comment: oh awesome, thanks for this. I got a little ahead of myself when I suggested it might be "very safe", since we still at least have the problem of comparing thunks with values, and all the complications that inlining might cause there. I would guess something like that is going on here, but I can't exactly see what...

Comment: I thought using `if b then a' else Just ()` would surely make it work. I was wrong. It's indeed really evil :)

Comment: Oddly enough, adding a bang pattern to `a` makes `ptrCmp` return True.  I think I understand why it doesn't work without the bang pattern: it's evil.

Comment: It's because of laziness! The ternary expression is a suspended computation. When you compare the pointers, `a` is a pointer to a thunk, not a pointer to `Nothing`. Forcing `a` by putting a bang in `ptrCmp` forces the thunk, which explains @JohnL's result.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson That explanation doesn't seem complete to me; doesn't `print (a == a')` force `a` and `a'`, leaving them non-thunks by the time `ptrCmp` is called?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point, I guess I didn't read the code carefully enough. In that case, I dunno.

Comment: For what it's worth: putting a `performMinorGC` after `print (a == a')` but before `print (ptrCmp a a')` causes it to print `True` for the second one. So it looks like @ThomasMDuBuisson had it right in his comment above.

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to get a false positive (ie `ptrCmp a b == True && (a == b) == False`)? Maybe equality performance can be imporoved by `fastSafeEq a b = ptrCmp a b || a == b` (for deterministic objects)?