# Huge memory consumption for simple multithreaded Haskell

Tags: multithreading, haskell, queue, ghc

I have a relatively simple "copy" program that merely copies all the lines of one file to another. I'm playing around with Haskell's concurrency support with `TMQueue` and `STM` so I thought I'd try it like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module Main where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Concurrent.Async              -- from async
import Control.Concurrent.Chan
import Control.Concurrent.STM (atomically)
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TMQueue        -- from stm-chans
import Control.Monad (replicateM, forM_, forever, unless)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Data.Function (fix)
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes, maybe)
import System.IO (withFile, IOMode(..), hPutStrLn, hGetLine)
import System.IO.Error (catchIOError)

input  = "data.dat"
output = "out.dat"
batch = 100 :: Int

consumer :: TMQueue B.ByteString -> IO ()
consumer q = withFile output WriteMode $ \fh -> fix $ \loop -> do
  !items <- catMaybes <$> replicateM batch readitem
  forM_ items $ B.hPutStrLn fh
  unless (length items < batch) loop
  where
    readitem = do
      !item <- atomically $ readTMQueue q
      return item

producer :: TMQueue B.ByteString -> IO ()
producer q = withFile input ReadMode $ \fh ->
  (forever (B.hGetLine fh >>= atomically . writeTMQueue q))
  `catchIOError` const (atomically (closeTMQueue q) >> putStrLn "Done")

main :: IO ()
main = do
  q <- atomically newTMQueue
  thread <- async $ consumer q
  producer q
  wait thread
```

I can make a little test input file like this

```
ghc -e 'writeFile "data.dat" (unlines (map show [1..5000000]))'
```

And build it like this

```
ghc --make QueueTest.hs -O2 -prof -auto-all -caf-all -threaded -rtsopts -o q
```

When I run it like so `./q +RTS -s -prof -hc -L60 -N2`, it says that "2117 MB total memory in use"! But the input file is only 38 MB!

I am new to profiling, but I have produced graph after graph and cannot pinpoint my mistake.

Comment: I blame the queue. If you exchange `TMQueue` with `TBMQueue` and an appropriate bound (say, 10 * batch), you have ~3 MB total memory use.

Comment: What did you learn from `-hc`, and what does `-hy` show? What does it say when you compile without profiling and just run with `+RTS -s -N`?

Comment: @Zeta I'll try it. However, in my real-life situation, I cannot allow the producer to block. I am extremely curious why TMQueue would have such a horrid affect on performance!

Comment: unagi-chan to the rescue! ;)

Comment: @3noch my initial thought is that unagi-chan wouldn't make much difference in this situation, I'd be interested to know if it significantly improves memory usage.

Comment: Hmm, it does seem to help memory usage a lot.  It's still pretty inefficient memory-wise though.

Comment: Incidentally, the basic problem is that the producer far outstrips the consumer, so there's a big backlog of data to process.  I think that, because unagi-chan uses a more memory-efficient representation, it ends up using less memory even though it suffers from the same problem.  If you can't allow your producer to block, then you need to be prepared for possible spikes in memory usage whenever the consumer lags.  It's also possible to force the consumer to disconnect and re-sync, but that can result in lost items.

Comment: @JohnL Yeah, I noticed that the producer outran the consumer because it prints "Done" a few seconds before finishing. But I don't understand the 55x memory overhead. While unagi-chan does use a ton more memory than a reasonably configured TBMQueue, it is actually faster, which is what I expected/hoped from TMQueue.

Comment: @3noch well, unagi-chan is several orders of magnitude faster than `MVar`-like chans.  Also this isn't a good test of parallelism because it's IO-bound and the only significant CPU load is from the channel operations.  If your actual program involves more significant processing in the pipeline, that will dominate and unagi's basic speed advantage won't contribute as much to the final results.

Comment: @JohnL I concede that this is a terrible concurrency test, but I still cannot get over the sticker-shock of 2GB memory usage. I could load the whole file into memory dozens of times before writing back and still have better memory usage. This test gave me serious pause as to TMQueue's viability in any situation, hence the question.

Comment: @3noch: it's not just `TMQueue`, it's a pretty common problem with several Haskell data structures, lists as well.  Not every data structure scales well in all situations, you should see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254758/memory-footprint-of-haskell-data-types for more information.

Comment: Oh I'm glad `unagi-chan` helped (from what I gather)! I'm working on a bounded variant that should also have support for a `write` that fails rather than blocks, which might allow for some more flexible usage. If you can think of a bounded queue variant or operation that would help you for this use case, feel free to add it [here](https://github.com/jberryman/unagi-chan/issues/1)

Comment: @JohnL Sounds like you might have an answer to the question in hand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the OP points out, by now I may as well write a real answer.  Let's start with the memory consumption.

Two useful references are [Memory footprint of Haskell data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254758/memory-footprint-of-haskell-data-types) and http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/06/memory-footprints-of-some-common-data.html.  We'll also need to look at the definitions of some of our structures.

```
-- from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-chans-3.0.0.2/docs/src/Control-Concurrent-STM-TMQueue.html

data TMQueue a = TMQueue
    {-# UNPACK #-} !(TVar Bool)
    {-# UNPACK #-} !(TQueue a)
    deriving Typeable


-- from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.4.3/docs/src/Control-Concurrent-STM-TQueue.html

-- | 'TQueue' is an abstract type representing an unbounded FIFO channel.
data TQueue a = TQueue {-# UNPACK #-} !(TVar [a])
                       {-# UNPACK #-} !(TVar [a])
```

The `TQueue` implementation uses a standard functional queue with a read end and write end.

Let's set an upper bound on memory usage and assume that we read the entire file into the `TMQueue` before the consumer does anything.  In that case, the write end of our TQueue will contain a list with one element per input line (stored as a bytestring).  Each list node will look like

```
(:) bytestring tail
```

which takes 3 words (1 per field + 1 for the constructor).  Each bytestring is 9 words, so add the two together and there are 12 words of overhead **per line**, not including the actual data.  Your test data is 5 million lines, so that's 60 million words of overhead for the whole file (plus some constants), which on a 64-bit system is about 460MB (assuming I did my math right, always questionable).  Add in 40MB for the actual data, and we get values pretty close to what I see on my system.

So, why is our memory usage close to this upper bound?  I have a theory (investigation left as an exercise!).  First, the producer is likely to run a bit faster than the consumer simply because reading is usually faster than writing (I'm using spinning disks, maybe an SSD would be different).  Here's the definition of readTQueue:

```
-- |Read the next value from the 'TQueue'.
readTQueue :: TQueue a -> STM a
readTQueue (TQueue read write) = do
  xs <- readTVar read
  case xs of
    (x:xs') -> do writeTVar read xs'
                  return x
    [] -> do ys <- readTVar write
             case ys of
               [] -> retry
               _  -> case reverse ys of
                       [] -> error "readTQueue"
                       (z:zs) -> do writeTVar write []
                                    writeTVar read zs
                                    return z
```

First we try to read from the read end, and if that's empty we try to read from the write end, after reversing that list.

What I think is happening is this: when the consumer needs to read from the write end, it needs to traverse the input list *within the STM transaction*.  This takes some time, which will cause it to contend with the producer.  As the producer gets further ahead, this list gets longer, causing the read to take yet more time, during which the producer is able to write more values, causing the read to fail.  This process repeats until the producer finishes, and only then does the consumer get a chance to process the bulk of the data.  Not only does this ruin concurrency, it adds more CPU overhead because the consumer transaction is continually retrying and failing.

So, what about unagi?  There are a couple key differences.  First, unagi-chan uses arrays internally instead of lists.  This reduces the overhead a little.  Most of the overhead is from the ByteString pointers, so not much, but a little.  Secondly, unagi keeps chunks of arrays.  Even if we pessimistically assume that the producer always wins contentions, after the array gets filled it's pushed off the producer's side of the channel.  Now the producer is writing to a new array and the consumer reads from the old array.  This situation is near-ideal; there's no contention to shared resources, the consumer has good locality of reference, and because the consumer is working on a different chunk of memory there aren't issues with cache coherence.  Unlike my theoretical description of the `TMQueue`, now you're getting concurrent operations, allowing the producer to clear some of the memory usage so it never hits the upper bound.

As an aside, I think the consumer batching is not beneficial.  Handles are buffered by the IO subsystem already, so I don't think this gains anything.  For me performance improved a little when I changed the consumer to operate line-by-line anyway.

Now, what can you do about this problem?  Going from my working hypothesis that `TMQueue` is suffering from contention problems, and your specified requirements, you'll just need to use another type of queue.  Obviously unagi works pretty well.  I also tried `TMChan`, it was about 25% slower than unagi but used 45% less memory, so that could be a good option too.  (this isn't too surprising, `TMChan` has a different structure from `TMQueue` so it'll have different performance characteristics)

You could also try to change your algorithm so that the producer sends multi-line chunks.  This would lower the memory overhead from all the ByteStrings.

So, when is it ok to use `TMQueue`?  If the producer and consumer are about the same speed, or the consumer is faster, it should be ok.  Also, if processing times are non-uniform, or the producer runs in bursts, you'll probably get good amortized performance.  This is pretty much a worst-case situation, and perhaps it should be reported as a bug against `stm`?  I think if the read function were changed to

```
-- |Read the next value from the 'TQueue'.
readTQueue :: TQueue a -> STM a
readTQueue (TQueue read write) = do
  xs <- readTVar read
  case xs of
    (x:xs') -> do writeTVar read xs'
                  return x
    [] -> do ys <- readTVar write
             case ys of
               [] -> retry
               _  -> do writeTVar write []
                        let (z:zs) = reverse ys
                        writeTVar read zs
                        return z
```

it would avoid this problem.  Now the `z` and `zs` bindings should both be evaluated lazily, so the list traversal would happen outside this transaction, allowing the read operation to succeed sometimes under contention.  Assuming I'm correct about the issue in the first place, of course (and that this definition is lazy enough).  There might be other unexpected downsides though.

Comment: Phenomenal answer! Very grateful for your thorough analysis from all different angles. Have you considered filing your alternative `readTQueue` as a potential enhancement to `stm`?