# How does the state monad work? (without code explanation)

Tags: monads, state-monad

For the last number of months I've been taking some spare time here and there to read up on Monads. I haven't worked with a functional language since my University days. So I don't really remember Haskell, and certainly have no idea about Scalaz.

It was a trying time learning about onions, burritos, and sandwiches while trying to correlate these foods to wads of Haskell code. Luckily I stumbled upon two key writeups which gave me the a-ha moment: monads in pictures, and another guy from an imperative coding background who simply wrote the equivalent of:

```
a -> b becomes m[a] -> m[b] (functor)
a -> m[b] becomes m[a] -> m[b] (monad)
and applicative is just a "function with context"
```

Together with the simplest sentence describing bind's purpose, many categories of endofunctors exploded and fizzled into simplicity.

Identity, List, Maybe and others suddenly made sense. Fueled with this knowledge I started to look toward trying some TMP in C++ using monadic types to see how it would pan out.

Very soon I wanted to propagate state. I think I've now read more articles on the state monad and monad transformers than I did for monads to begin with but for the life of me I can't figure them. Many keyboards have worn out I'm sure with all the words typed on these topics answering people like me.

But I ask you to suffer one more.

```
a -> s -> (b, s)
```

Function takes a value and some state, returns a new value and (possibly) modified state. Bind would clearly need to propagate both the return value and state into the next function.

My issue is this: monad's work because they impose a structure. Sticking to the structure and obeying the laws leads to funtimes and rainbows. However a -> s -> (b, s) does not look like the monadic a -> m[b].

Even if 'a' is applied, it's still s -> (b, s). The difference being that the latter function takes a (monadic?) STATE and returns state WITH a value. Whereas the regular form is: takes a VALUE and returns a WRAPPED value.

Both the parameter(s) going in vary as well as the form of the return type. Yet many articles are saying this clearly looks like a monad. It sure doesn't to me.

If I were to relax the view I've been told has to be held: Instead of bind applying m[a] to a -> m[b], it takes whatever parameter makes sense for the monad and applies it to whatever function signature makes sense... then I could see it working.

As in that case I could simply say "oh this monad binds State[s] AND 'a' to a function like a -> State[s] -> (State[s], b)". It could then expect a tuple return and unpack that into the arguments for the next function.

But somehow I suspect there IS a way of making the state monad work like all the others - including expecting the form a -> m[b] somehow (but then how does it thread the state through?). I suspect this can be done because I believe writing Monad Transformers will rely on these function signatures (forms?) being consistent.

Even if you don't have time to type out a big response, a link to an article more from an imperative programmers perspective would be a godsend.

(And apologies for any incorrect use of terminology - I'm kind of picking that up along the way too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the monad instance under discussion *does* preserve `State` structure and that the tuple is throwing you for a loop when it should not.

If we take a step back and ask what signature should bind have in order to match up with our monad expectations, we get this:

```
(>>=) :: State s a -> (a -> State s b) -> State s b
someState >>= someFuncOfA = ...
```

and I'll put extra brackets around the monadic value constructor, which remember is `State s` and *not* merely `State` since a concrete type cannot be made an instance of Monad, only a type constructor of one argument:

```
(>>=) :: [State s] a -> (a -> [State s] b) -> [State s] b
someState >>= someFuncOfA = ...
```

where `[State s]` will be our special `m` from all the monad stuff.

Since the newtype for `State` is

```
newtype State s a = State s -> (a, s)
```

we know that whatever it means to value-construct a `State` *value*, the parameter that the value takes is a *function* `s -> (a, s)`.

So back up in our incomplete bind definition:

```
(>>=) :: [State s] a -> (a -> [State s] b) -> [State s] b
someState >>= someFuncOfA = ...
```

we know that the `...` is going to have to be `State $ (someNewFunc)` cause that's how `State` gets value-constructed.

First observation: the tuple doesn't have much to do with this. It is *the function* `someNewFunc` that, so long as it's type matches what's needed to value-construct `State`, maintains our desired monadic structure. The fact that *that function* happens to need to have type `s -> (a, s)` is pretty much just an implementation choice. The signature could be a lot of different things, and since there's [not really a difference between tuples and value constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476446/what-is-the-difference-between-value-constructors-and-tuples), I'm sure you could first make a special `data` type whose value constructor acted like a two-tuple for this purpose and made the signatures seem artificially nicer.

Second observation: `State` does not have an exported `'State'` value constructor, at least not from `Control.Monad.State`, so you use the helper function

```
state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> State s a
```

which again takes a *function* as its first parameter and does the value-constructing behind the scenes.

So we know that inside of the bind definition, we're not going to be able to write

```
someState >>= someFuncOfA = State $ (someFunc)
```

instead it will need to be

```
someState >>= someFuncOfA = state $ (someFunc)
```

and `state $ (someFunc)` *when evaluated* leads to type `State s a` because `someFunc` is forced to have type `(s -> (a,s))` and will in fact use `runState` to accomplish this.

This may not be a very good write-up. It was my attempt to translate the relevant portions of the [FP Complete State Monad tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/12-State-Monad) into something that addressed this particular question. Perhaps reading that will provide a better description.

Comment: Ill be honest - I didnt quite follow all of that. I also reread the FPComplete writeup for what must be the 3rd time. However one thing you said plus one thing the FPComplete said lead me to the a-ha moment. I'm going to write up what the sticking point was (for me) just in case others may be hung up on the same issue. I don't really know whether that means I should mark yours as the accepted answer or what. But I'll come back to this on Monday. For now, thanks - you certainly were a stepping stone on the way there. :-)

Answer (score 1):

With a re-read of FPComplete, the answer by Mr.F and another SO answer on state monads I finally had my a-ha moment.

What really confused me was being locked into thinking about *values*. Armed with the monads I was already familiar with, I had this mental block where I kept trying to think of the state monad as augmenting with a value - so in part Mr.F was right that the tuple was confusing me and unnecessarily so.

I think there are two things about the state monad which really made it click:

- Its job isnt to add *information* (like the Maybe monad might add a Bool), but rather to add an *ability*.
- The best way to see what its doing is to look at its *return*.

The way state is dealt with in functional programming is to thread it through as one of the parameters and part of the return. So the state monad is about threading that state through. In other words it amplifies something which is unable to thread state into something which is able to thread state.

If one has a value of type 'a', the way to enable this to have state threaded through it is to make it into a function: s -> s a

This is what the state monad's return does. For example if I have an Int of value 5, the state monad's return would give me a function: s -> s 5 (now the value '5' can have state threaded through it in a manner of speaking).

Of course *bind* works with a function that is of the form a -> mb.

So since State wraps a function which takes a state value and returns a state value (along with the regular return value for the function!), the expected form of a State-aware function is: a -> mb where the mb we already know to be a function which can 'thread' state. So it behaves a lot like a -> s -> sb.

The conclusion of this is that any function a -> b, or any value 'a' can now be amplified by the State monad to gain the ability to have state threaded through it. Now it can easily be chained (bind) with functions that are State-aware.

This clears up something else that was bugging me: why the example Haskell code (which I didn't completely understand) had to have this extra run step at the end.

Once everything has been amplified to thread state, the binds have been called, whats left is actually a function. Its chained all the a's, b's, c's using bind and fmap to finally return s r (state and a result). But its still missing one thing: the actual initial state.

So you need to 'run' or 'evaluate' the resulting computation by providing an initial state.

HUGE thanks to FPComplete, Mr. F and a great SO answer whose link I have already lost :)

Rainbows and unicorns until I decide to tackle Monad Transformers now.

Comment: I still think there is an issue with statements like "So this is already of the a -> mb form because for the state monad, mb is a function which takes and returns state. So mb is the (s -> sb) part of the aforementioned function." That's not really true. The `m b` part *is not* the function ... the function *is merely the thing needed to value-construct a State data type.* That part could have been implemented in alternative ways (maybe better, maybe worse) but is not structurally important to the whole  `(>>=) :: [State s] a -> (a -> [State s] b) -> [State s] b` type structure.

Comment: It's `[State s] b` that is the `m b` part, and it *merely* happens to be the case (via `return` and the way `runState` is used within the `state` helper function) that it gets value constructed in this particular function-based manner. You are quite right about the threading-things-through, such that values become functions of values of functions of values of .... and so on, but it is important to be very precise about what the monadic values are and what they are not.

Comment: @Mr.F thank you for the clarification. I do understand that the (s -> sb), while being a function, is the value used to construct the State data type. I'll reword that part because what I said is that a -> s -> sb is already correct when the way I understand it, its a -> State(s -> sb) which is how it should be (being the function should return an instance of the state monad).

Comment: @Mr.F Something I am still not sure of is the '[State s] b' usage. Unfortunately along with my lack of Haskell knowledge is also a lack of how to interpret the various symbols used. Perhaps I really should just spend some time to read some intro's to Haskell.

Comment: Keep in mind that the square bracket there is not valid Haskell, it's purely meant to aide in reading, to highlight the fact that `State s` can be made an instance of `Monad` but `State` cannot. Just like how `Either a` can be made an instance of `Monad` but `Either` cannot.

Comment: @Mr.F it's quite likely I'm still missing some bit of understanding. I'm going to give it more consideration because, as you say, the small details are important to get right; to know exactly where the line is between the monad itself and the implementation choice. Thank you very much for your reply. You have no idea how trying understanding this (reasonably) simple concept has been.